# How can I match a horizontal position in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

In a regular expression, how can I match a character at a certain horizontal
position? I would like to replace a comma at position `n` with a comma followed
by three spaces, i.e.

```
s/,/, /        # replace ',' at position n=4 with ', '
```

but these regular expressions still miss the horizontal position constraint.

Together with

```
s/,/,  /       # replace ',' at position n=3 with ',  '
s/,/,   /      # replace ',' at position n=2 with ',   '
```

I want to use it to re-formatting data columns, from

```
1,10000,0.187929453,10000
162,28000,0.045417083,28000
22,100000,0.020914811,100000
64,1000,0.234950091,10000
65,46000,0.037523632,46000
66,118000,0.015378538,118000
```

to

```
1,   10000,  0.187929453, 10000
162, 28000,  0.045417083, 28000
22,  100000, 0.020914811, 100000
64,  1000,   0.234950091, 10000
65,  46000,  0.037523632, 46000
66,  118000, 0.015378538, 118000
```

Comment: You can use the dot `.` which in regexprs match any character; and `awk` is perhaps a better tool....

Comment: I don't see regular expression here as part of the solution either. It seems, that knowledge about the longest integer in the data column is necessary here to determine the number of spaces. This requires a fully-fledged two pass processing. The format is somewhat unusual also, I would rather expect the least significant digits to align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
s/^(.{3}),/$1,   /
```

The syntax depends on your language. The above works for Perl. In some languages it's `\1` instead of `$1`.

Most languages have much easier ways of doing what you want. Perl and C has `printf` to format outputs:

```
#another Perl example:
printf '%4s %7s %s %s', map({ $_ . ',' }, split(',',$line));
```

Comment: You should add a start of line anchor to your regex, otherwise it will just match any arbitrary comma preceded by 4 characters.

Also that would replace any commas at position `/(.{n-1}),/` i.e. the above regex replaces commas at position n=5 (not 4) - good to know for whoever is using it.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use regex here, this type of problem can be easily solved using awk. Consider following code:

```
awk -F"," 'NF==4{printf("%-5s%-8s%-12s %s\n", $1",", $2",", $3",", $4)}' in.file
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/bXJXX5